# Send data to Android from Java EE

Tags: java, android, sockets, jakarta-ee

I am trying to send data over TCP/IP from a Java EE application to an Android app. In Android I have the following in a AsyncTask:

```
try {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(48760);

    while (true) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        // Do something interesting with sent data
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have verified that the app executes until it blocks at the accept() call, as expected.

on the server side (Java EE) I use:

```
// address contains the IP of the android device as a string.
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(address); 
Socket conn = new Socket(addr, 48760);
```

Here I get "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" when the application reaches "new Socket()". Any ideas as to why this is?

I have  in my manifest. And the ip in "address" seems to be the correct one (the ip provided by my service provider).

Is there a better way of sending messages? I was planing on using Serializable objects (from Android to JavaEE I use HTTP, through a Servlet) but I am open for suggestions.

Comment: I think you have this back to front.  It would be more realistic to have the J2EE application as the server

Comment: @scarywombat but what do I do if the j2ee application needs to notify the client (or perhaps multiple clients) of some change or similar? Could I use a similar approach or is perhaps Java Message Service possible to implement?

Comment: but maybe the device would not even be turned on.  You would have to keep track of which device has received the message etc.  Easier just to have the device to **poll** the J2EE Application

Comment: I'm thinking you are probably right. I'll think of a new design, where the devices polls the j2ee app, and see if that works out the way I'd like. Thanks for your input, much appreciated!

Comment: Actually polling is bad advice, as it causes unnecessary overload to the server. Use websockets.

Comment: Websockets are very easy to use in JavaEE, way easier than java.net.Socket

Comment: @MouseEvent thanks for your input, I've been reading the RFC for WebSockets and it seems like something I could use. It seems J2EE has good support (I'm reading the tutorial at the moment). But I'm not sure about the android side of things, it seems to me like there is no native support, correct?

Comment: Not really in Android so i'm not sure. But in worst case, there are many libraries in the wild for websocket "client" support.

Comment: Yep, Android does have a native push notification system, GCM.

Answer (score 0):

Okay there is a problem with your implement !

Why you need to connect from server to client (who cares but client is server now !) !?

You must fix this problem !

And lets show you what is your problem !

If your server (JAVA EE Server) is on public internet so it means your server has a **public IP** address . This **public IP** address is accessible from all devices that connected to internet ! You can control all ports of server and so on ... , so every one can connect to your web application in public Internet.

But in **client side** somethings are difference !
When you connect to internet in **client side** this will happen :

- **1** - Your device connect to router (it can be a modem in your home or mobile service)
- **2** - Your router has an **IP address** in **IPS** network and **ISP** network translate it (using **[NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)**) to a possible public IP
- **3** - now your device(s) has the same **IP** as that **IP** assigned to your router in **ISP**

**Your problem is in section 2** ! because most of **ISP**(s) ***share*** a **public IP** between clients so it means when your assigned **IP** is **ADDR_1** there is another clients that has the same **IP** **ADDR_1** and you cant control all ports on it . Maybe when you listening on port 8080 in your **local network** the **ISP** assign another port for your **public IP** (Regardless of **[NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)** will block your listening ports in most of **ISP**(s))

So every clients doesn't have unique IP and too hard to find them in public internet (it will be harder when new **NAT**(s) **[[Symmetric-NAT]](https://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/09/19/symmetric-nat/)** exists on ISP)

There is several ways to handle this problem , but there isn't any way to work 100% !